# How to install Backtrack 5 tool?

Tags: 11.10, installation

I have a problem with a Backtrack 5 installation. So I just want to install Backtrack 5 tool on my Ubuntu 11.10. Can it run on ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: IIRC BackTrack is a distribution, not just a tool you install in Ubuntu. Have a look at http://www.backtrack-linux.org/

Comment: I guess he means the Tools, Software, Applications that Backtrack has.

Comment: Well, aircrack-ng for example has been removed from the 12.04 repositories - not well maintained and last time I checked, I had to manually compile everything to make it work. IMO there's no reason to not use BackTrack 5 if you want to run those tools. :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't **install** BackTrack on another OS.

You either run it as a LiveCD, or you install it on a disk as the operating system. I assume you want to keep your existing operating system (your Ubuntu install) so don't try and install BackTrack over it; run it as a LiveCD or install it on another disk or partition.

Backtrack on USB stick works perfectly for penetration testing. I have one USB stick just for this purpose. You will need to ensure your machine can boot from USB (set this in the BIOS) and that the install you have on the stick is a Live install (ie bootable) and it should boot to BackTrack without any problem.

**Update**: the BackTrack FAQ says this about using BackTrack tools in Ubuntu and vice versa:

> Why cant I just add the Backtrack repositories to my Ubuntu install or
>   the Ubuntu repositories to my Backtrack install ?
>
> We highly recommend against this action because Backtrack tools are
>   built with many custom features, libraries and kernel. We have no way
>   of knowing how they will perform on a non Backtrack distribution, plus
>   you will very quickly break your install. Also if you chose to add the
>   ubuntu repositories to your Backtrack install, you will most certainly
>   break your entire Backtrack install very quickly. We do a lot of
>   testing to ensure that all packages in our repo will work together
>   without causing problems. If you decide on this course of action you
>   do so entirely at your own risk and the backtrack team will not offer
>   any support in any way.

Comment: but I used mobile broadband and it hard to connect with backtrack

Comment: Can you explain what mobile broadband has to do with this. When you have downloaded the BackTrack ISO you just burn it to a CD/DVD. You don't need a connection once you have it downloaded; just run the CD

Comment: I run it on usb stick.But the problem is I don't now how to connect mobile broadband on Backtrack 5.It's dificult and different from other linux

Comment: here the other promlem with Backtrack installation.When 99% complete installation it come with this errno5 input/output error.

Comment: Broadly speaking, it's just Kubuntu, which is just Ubuntu. The difference is that it is designed for a specific purpose and a lot of extraneous stuff has been removed so you may just need to sort out whatever module you need for broadband.

Comment: re that install error, look at the BackTrack FAQ: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ - specifically the section headed "I’ve just burned my iso and it will not boot ?"

Comment: ok I will try right now.TQ for helping

Answer (score 0):

BackTrack is a Linux Distro, you cannot install it over ubuntu. You need to install it as a separate OS on another partition if you want to keep your ubuntu side by side.

Comment: even petration tool?

Comment: The BackTrack distro contains many penetration tools already bundled with it.

Comment: you can install those penetration tools on ubuntu also, if you are looking to work with any particular penetration tool, then check the documentation of those tools and the installation steps for installing in ubuntu. But if you dont want to take the pain of installing each and every tool individually on ubuntu, then you can directly use BackTrack as live CD or install in another partition

Comment: can you give link for penetration tool for my ubuntu 11.10

Comment: What penetration tool? can u give me a name?

Comment: @iehJulianec There are hundreds of tools bundled into BackTrack, from many different sources. If you read the BackTrack FAQ you can find links to all of them.

Comment: Check metaspoilt framework, you can install it on ubuntu. http://metasploit.com/

Comment: If I say all of penetration tool on Backtrack 5.Can U give that

Comment: According to BackTrack site, there is no way to get the complete list of tools installed in backtrack, check this http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_a_complete_list_of_all_the_tools_installed_in_BackTrack_.3F

Comment: But you can run the BackTrack Live CD and note down the penetration tools installed using dpkg --list and check each tool individually

Comment: I checked your profile, if you are looking to learn the tools, start checking each tool individually, it will help you learning them. There is no point installation 100s of tools and applications without knowing what they actually do?

Comment: can U give me maxsimum penetration tool could can be istall on my Ubuntu?